# How to add a column with specific values to an existing database table

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, window-functions

I needed an advice regarding a SQL statement that has to run with DB2 and Oracle.

Some time ago a database table has been set up without an ID column. Adding the ID column is not the problem but I absolutely need to fill it with the row number of each row. 
I found out, that rank() would be perfect but here I'm not able to select for specific values because then I always get the value '1'.

When I set up an intermediate table as described below, I output all data, that I need

```
WITH MY_TEMP_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CODE ASC) MY_ROW, CODE, LAND  
    FROM SECOND_TABLE
) 
SELECT *
FROM SECOND_TABLE
INNER JOIN MY_TEMP_TABLE ON SECOND_TABLE.CODE=MY_TEMP_TABLE.CODE
```

How is it possible to update the ID column in the database table (here: SECOND_TABLE) with the values in MY_ROW?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: what do you mean by that you always get the value 1? where do you get the value 1? in my_row?

Comment: I think you want [ROWNUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) rather than RANK().

Comment: SELECT  ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE ASC) MY_ROW, CODE, LAND FROM BDV_KFWSTAAT<BR/>
 does return more than 200 results of which each has a different number<BR/>

SELECT  ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE ASC) MY_ROW, CODE, LAND FROM BDV_KFWSTAAT where code='DE'<BR/>
returns the value '1' not regarding what where I use. This way it I'm not able to differ between the results.

The problem is the same with rank() and rownumber()

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data (_formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number() instead of rank():

```
WITH MY_TEMP_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CODE ASC) MY_ROW, CODE, LAND  
    FROM SECOND_TABLE
) 
SELECT *
FROM SECOND_TABLE
INNER JOIN MY_TEMP_TABLE ON SECOND_TABLE.CODE=MY_TEMP_TABLE.CODE
```

Comment: Thank you all so far... My problem goes a bit deeper... How is it possible to combine the output of this code with an "update" statement in order fill the data into SECOND_TABLE.ID? I needed a example code therefore.

Comment: Can't you create a new table and populate it correctly?